# What is the best way to access the date_added column from the order table in opencart?

Tags: opencart

I'm working with the latest version of opencart. I'd like to access the current value for the date_added column from the order table. What would be the best way to access this so I can echo out the current date_added value on the checkout/success page? I know I can grab the most recent date_added value straight from the database using a mysql query. But is there a better way to do this? For example is this variable stored in the session somewhere, or in an array somewhere? If so, please give an example of the code I could use to do this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to load the order based on the `order_id` which is stored in

```
$this->session->data['order_id']
```

up until the success page, at which point the order_id and all other order information gets removed. So you will need to capture the `order_id` before this in `/catalog/controller/checkout/success.php` and load the order from there

It's recommended you use the `getOrder()` method of the `sale/order` model rather than using SQL directly. Just getting the latest date from the database is a bit haphazard as there can be orders between the time the current users' is created and when they get the success message (note the date added is not the date they are at the `checkout/success` necessarily)